# Trouble with elif statements in a Python login system and setting a login attempt limit

Tags: python

'm working on a login system where there are multiple employees and one admin. Each has specific functionalities:

Employees can view their salary.
The admin can modify employee salaries.
The employee data is stored in a data.txt file with fields like id, username, and salary. Here's the code I have so far:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:  # Is this the right way to read from the data.txt file?
    data = f.readlines()

user_data = {}  # Renamed from dict for clarity and to avoid overriding built-in type
for r in data:
    fields = r.split(",")
    id, username, date, gender, salary = fields
    user_data[username] = {"id": id, "name": username, "date of joining": date, "gender": gender, "salary": salary}

def log_in(username, password):
      if username in user_data and password=="":
    # employee logic here...
      elif username not in user_data and password=="":
    # another logic here...
    # ... more elif/else conditions ...

username = input("Enter a username: ")
password = input("Enter a password: ")
log_in(username, password)
```

I'm facing two main issues:

Some of the elif statements inside the log_in function don't seem to work as intended. Can someone help pinpoint the errors?
How can I implement a feature that gives the admin only 5 attempts to login?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think that the `elif` statements are not working?

Comment: The question is about "some of the elif statements inside the log_in function" not working, so editing the code to remove all those statements doesn't make sense.

Comment: Fixed, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: No problem, but it would help to be more specific - for example, what particular inputs cause the code to produce unexpected results, and what are the results?

Comment: yea honestly I solved the issue a long time ago, but I was banned to ask questions from a bot and he told me to improve my questions so that's why, teh post is almost 1 year old. Thanks anyways <3